# Convert image to numpy.net array

Tags: c#, python.net

How can Image be converted into numpy.array in c# , currently i am using below code but at runtime it says **Type System.Drawing.Image[] not supported yet in ConvertArrayToNDarray**

```
var image_array = np.asarray<Image>(new[] { imageToTest });
```

The similar python code for this which i am trying to convert to C# is below

```
# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open('test_photo.jpg')

#resize the image to a 224x224 with the same strategy as in TM2:
#resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

#turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)
```